# Best way to structure my firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project where users can post things. But, I'm wondering if my firebase database structure is efficient. Below is how my database looks like so far. I have posts child contains all the post that users will post. and each user will be able to track their own posts by having `posts` child in `uid`. Is there a better way of structuring my data? or am I good to go? Any advice would be appreciated!

```
{
 "posts" : {
     "-KVRT-4z1AUoztWnF-pe" : {
     "caption" : "",
     "likes" : 0,
     "pictureUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cloub-4fdbd.appspot.com/o/users%2FufTgaqudXeUciW5bGgCSfoTRUw92%2F208222E1-8E20-42A0-9EEF-8AF34F523878.png?alt=media&token=9ec5301e-d913-44ee-81d0-e0ec117017de",
     "timestamp" : 1477946376629,
     "writer" : "ufTgaqudXeUciW5bGgCSfoTRUw92"
     }
 }, 
 "users" : {
     "ufTgaqudXeUciW5bGgCSfoTRUw92" : {
         "email" : "Test1@gmail.com",
         "posts" : {
             "-KVRT-4z1AUoztWnF-pe" : {
                 "timestamp" : 1477946376677
             }
         },
         "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cloub-4fdbd.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2F364DDC66-BDDB-41A4-969E-397A79ECEA3D.png?alt=media&token=c135d337-a139-475c-b7a4-d289555b94ca",
         "username" : "Test1"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no single best way to structure your data. It all depends on how you want to use that data in your app. I recommend reading this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with **NoSql** Data , your need to take care of few things:-

- *Avoid Nesting The Data Too Deep*
- *Flatten your dataStructure as possible*
- *Prefer Dictionaries*
- *Security Rules* [**Firebase**]

Try this structure:-

```
users:{
  userID1: {..//Users info..
             posts:{
                 postID1: true,
                 postID2: true,
                 postID3: true,  
                    }
                 },
  userID2: {..//Users info..},
  userID3: {..//Users info..},
  userID4: {..//Users info..},
    },
posts: {
 userID1 :{
  postID1: {..//POST CONTENT },
  postID2: {..//POST CONTENT },
  postID3: {..//POST CONTENT },
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the data flat and shallow. Store data elsewhere in the tree rather than nest a branch of data under a node that is simply related, duplicating the data if that helps to keep the tree shallow.

The goal is to have fast requests that return only data you need. Consider that every time the tree changes and the client-side listener fires the node and all its children are communicated to the client. Duplication of data across the tree facilitates quick requests with minimal data.

This process of flattening the data is known as "denormalization" and this section of the Firebase Doc does a nice job of providing guidance:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data

In your example above I see posts metadata nested under "users", a nested list that grows. Every time something changes under "users" the listener will fire to update the client and all of this data will be transmitted in each response. You could instead consider to fetch the posts data from the "posts" node based on the writer's uuid.

Comment: You mean, instead of fetching post data by unique postId, fetch it by the writer's uid? Then, what if users have more than one post, how would you distinguish between posts?

Comment: Instead of the other root being "posts" you could duplicate the writer's uuid as a node with the posts as children.  That way your fetch is "Get me all the posts for this user" rather than "Get me everything about this user including all their posts".  It would make it simpler to use a a RecyclerView for the posts, too.