# Is this a good way to structure my firebase database?

Tags: firebase, nosql

I'm just starting out with Firebase (moving across from MySQL) and, after reading many documents/watching tutorials I've tried to structure the database for my "Ebay/Gumtree style app". Are there any major issues with what I've gone with?

I've sort of tried to structure it around each screen on my app so that I'm not reading a whole load of data that isn't needed (I think this is the flat structure I should be going for?), however this had led to some duplication of data (specifically images).

Is this a good way to structure the database? I've taken a few tips from here:

[Best way to structure my firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351162/best-way-to-structure-my-firebase-database)

```
{
  "users": {
      "user1": {
          "email": "example@gmail.com",
          "password": "********",
          "first name": "Example",
          "last name": "User",
          "age": "45",
          "gender": "Male",
          "address": "XX1 9YY"
        }
      },
  "upload image": {
      "user1": { 
          "image1": { #path to image
              "condition": "Like New",
              "price": "£100",
              "upload date": "10/10/2019",
              "promoted": True,
              "promoted expiry": "11/11/2019"
            },
          "image2": {
              "condition": "New",
              "price": "£250",
              "upload date": "12/12/2019",
              "promoted": False
            },
      "user2": {
          "image1": {
              "condition": "Used",
              "price": "£50",
              "upload date": "05/05/2019",
              "promoted": True,
              "promoted expiry": "06/06/2019"
            }
          },
  "promoted images": { #max 50 images stored here
      "user1": { 
          "image1": #This image is a duplicated of the image above
              "condition": "Like New",
              "price": "£100",
              "upload date": "10/10/2019",
              "promoted": True,
              "promoted expiry": "11/11/2019"
            },
      "user2": {
          "image1": { #This image is also a duplicate
              "condition": "Used",
              "price": "£50",
              "upload date": "05/05/2019",
              "promoted": True,
              "promoted expiry": "06/06/2019"
            }
          },
  "categories": {
      "category1": {
          "image1": { #This is the third location image1 is stored
              "condition": "Used",
              "price": "£50",
              "upload date": "05/05/2019",
              "promoted": True,
              "promoted expiry": "06/06/2019"
            },
          "image2": {
              "condition": "New",
              "price": "£250",
              "upload date": "12/12/2019",
              "promoted": False
            }
          },
   "reviews": {
       "user1": {
           "review1": {
               "rating": 4,
               "message": "delivered on time, thanks"
            },
           "review2": {
               "rating": 5,
               "message": "great product, delivered quickly"
            },
           }
       "user2": {
           "review1": {
               "rating": 1,
               "message": "terrible service, took ages to arrive and was faulty!"
            },
          },
       },
    },
}
```

Some questions/thoughts as to why I've done things so far:

Is it a good idea to have multiple copies of the same image as it would save going through 1000s of images. For example, if I didn't have "promoted images" but wanted to find all promoted images i'd have to search through the "upload image" section (which will have many many more images than the 50 in "promoted images"

Each "category" is a new screen that will load lots of images so I've tried to separate this section out, rather than having a master "category" that gets read everytim any of the pages load.

Thanks

Comment: well there are so many things to point out. but before that i ll recommend you to use firestore for such app. its not a real time thing. so dont use RTDB for this

Comment: Ah OK, is firestore so different that this example isn't going to be very useful for firestore?

Comment: you ll be billed more with RTDB for this use case and it cant scale easily so go for firestore

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll use firestore instead. What things would you point out about the above code?

Comment: @example I disagree with that statement - *its not a real time thing* doesn't apply because both the RTDB and Firestore are 100% Real Time. Being billed more with the RTDB is going to be subjective; RTDB billing is based on how much data whereas Firestore is based on number of reads/writes and I would think an ebay type app would have a significant number of reads/writes based on how many times users bid on an item. OP - your Firebase structure is dependent on what you want to get out of it, and we don't know what that is. BUT - you should NOT store images in either. Store images in Storage.

Comment: ...And here's the link [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). Doing that will alleviate the amount of data being stored in the RTDB and probably make it more cost effective.

Comment: when i say real time thing i mean you wont be doing frequest I/O like in a chat or iot kind of use case. you may disagree with whatever you want. i have made more than 50 projects with these database and i wont make such a project with RTDB

Comment: i have also taken other things into consideration like data storage bills and scaling. RTDB is good for frequesnt I/O. not for such use cases

Comment: Thanks both, I'll use my current code as a start point. It's good to check I've made no serious errors that will cost me down the line! I will be storing just URLs and having the images in storage, thanks for the link